# Object is possibly 'undefined' using @Input in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I want to display this child comp `app-single-ticket` in the parent comp,

while `single-ticket` comp should display parent data `ticket`

```
<ul>
      <li *ngFor="let ticket of tickets">
        <app-single-ticket [tickets]="ticket"></app-single-ticket>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

accessing the passed `ticket` object from the parent inside the child works fine

but when accessing the properties of that Object I get

`<span>{{ticket.id}}</span> {{ticket.text}}`

`Object is possibly 'undefined'`

I have used a interface to set a datatype but it looks like it has no effect

`@Input() ticket?: Ticket`

Comment: Because the `?` in `prop?` means that `prop` is optional. If not provided it will be `undefined`

Comment: how can I ressolve that ?

Comment: You can use `<span>{{ticket?.id ?? ''}}</span> {{ticket?.text ?? ''}} `

Answer (score 0):

Use an exclamation mark

```
@Input() ticket!: Ticket;
```

And inside the component, add the null check

```
<ng-container *ngIf="ticket">
    <span>{{ticket.id}}</span> {{ticket.text}}
</ng-container>
```